# How to assign a user to a role using Asp Dot Net Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I would like to assign a user to a role in the AspNetUserRoles table. But I can not figure out what is my mistake here.

1.The (string id) is the Id of the user that I would like to assign the role to.

2. I have tried using the id of the "Moderator" role but it still wouldn't work.

P.S. This is not upon creation of the account, just wanted to make that clear.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MakeModerator(string id)
    {

        var roles = _context.Roles.ToList();

       var roleId = _context.UserRoles.Where(u => u.UserId == id).Select(r => r.RoleId).SingleOrDefault();

       var userRole = roles.Where(r => r.Id == roleId).Select(n => n.Name).SingleOrDefault();

         var userToadd = new ShuttersIncUser { UserName = id };


        if (userRole != "Moderator" && userRole != "Admin")
        {
           await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userToadd, "Moderator");
           _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {

        }

        return RedirectToAction("AllUsers");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the user with Id or with userName and then assign the role.

```
var userToadd = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id); or 
var userToadd = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(id);
```

No need to use _context.SaveChanges . You can also inject RoleManager _roleManager in controller and then use _roleManager to get the roles instead of using the _context